# Website has same name with AD and it Keep point to default web page in IIS

Tags: iis, web-server, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I have configured a website `ws.example.com` in domain `example.com`, and my AD in domain name `ws.example.com`.
When I try to open the website(`ws.example.com`), it always leads me to the IIS default web page. I have tried to change the  default web page port. However, when I open `ws.example.com`, it shows 404 webpage not found.

The default web page binding setting:

| Type | Host Name | Port | IP Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http |  | 79 | * |

`ws.example.com` binding setting:

| Type | Host Name | Port | IP Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http | ws.example.com | 80 | 192.168.1.10 |

p.s. I only have one network interface

Answer (score 0):

You have the DNS configured but you must also configure the server software so that it knows which directory to serve.  The web server (IIS) determines which directory to serve based on host headers sent by the http client.
you must configure IIS to serve the directory you want for the site specified by the client.  I don't have any specific guidance on how to accomplish that since I don't know which version of IIS you are running and I am not a windows admin, but the following resources might help.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site-b440fffe-ab77-d86b-3836-623218ba7ab4

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis